# "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" error when opening second serial port

Tags: c#, port

i Need to open a second serialPort in my Visual C# program to read data from my arduino.
it already worked fine, but in the case you see below it does not work..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using CommandsPD4I;


namespace CSharpExample
{
public partial class CSharpExample : Form
{
    public ComMotorCommands motor1;

    public CSharpExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        motor1 = new ComMotorCommands();
        motor1.SetSteps(Convert.ToInt32(numericSchritte.Value));
    }
    SerialPort arduino;
    delegate void InvokeLB(string Data);
    InvokeLB lbRecievedDelegate;
    int xPos = 0;


    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set comm settings for motor 1
        motor1.SelectedPort = ComPortBox1.Text;
        motor1.Baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(BaudrateBox1.Text);

        // Set motor address
        motor1.MotorAddresse = Convert.ToInt32(Motor1ID.Value);
        // Set relative positioning mode
        motor1.SetPositionType(1);

        // Start travel profile
        if (motor1.ErrorFlag)
        {
            StatusLabel1.Text = "Status 1: " + motor1.ErrorMessageString;
        }
        else
        {
            StatusLabel1.Text = "Status 1: OK";
        }
    }

    private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop travel profile
        motor1.StopTravelProfile();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblPosition.Text = Convert.ToString(motor1.GetPosition());
        lblStatus.Text = motor1.ErrorMessageString;
       // this.chart1.Series["Kraft"].Points.AddXY(xPos, Convert.ToDouble(lblKraft.Text));
       // xPos++;**strong text**
    }

    private void btnHoch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        motor1.SetDirection(0);
        motor1.SetPositionType(1);
        motor1.StartTravelProfile();
    }

    private void btnRunter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        motor1.SetDirection(1);
        motor1.SetPositionType(1);
        motor1.StartTravelProfile();
    }

    private void numericSchritte_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        motor1.SetSteps(Convert.ToInt32(numericSchritte.Value));
    }

    private void numericGeschwindigkeit_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        motor1.SetMaxFrequency(Convert.ToInt32(numericGeschwindigkeit.Value));

    }

    private void btnDiagramm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private void btnResetDiagramm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.chart1.Series["Kraft"].Points.Clear();
        xPos = 0;
    }

    private void arduino_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string RecievedLine = " ";
        while (RecievedLine != "")
        {
            RecievedLine = arduino.ReadLine();
            lblKraft.Invoke(lbRecievedDelegate, new object[] { RecievedLine });

        }
    }

    void Invokelabel1(string Data)
    {
        label1.Text = Data;
        this.chart1.Series["Kraft"].Points.AddXY(xPos, Convert.ToDouble(lblKraft.Text));
        xPos++;
    }

    private void btnArduino_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Hier erstellen wir unseren Serialport und legen die Einstellungen fest
        arduino = new SerialPort("COM7", 9600);

        if (!arduino.IsOpen) 
        {
            arduino.Open();
            if (arduino.IsOpen)
            {
                lblArduino.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(200)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
                lblArduino.Text = "Verbunden mit " + arduino.PortName;
            }

        }
        lbRecievedDelegate = new InvokeLB(Invokelabel1);
        arduino.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(arduino_DataReceived); //DataRecieved Event abonnieren
    }



}
}
```

When i leave out this:

```
motor1.SelectedPort = ComPortBox1.Text;
motor1.Baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(BaudrateBox1.Text);
```

then it works..

I hope you can help :)